# Compare paths & ignoring case of drive letter

Tags: c#, directory, path, uppercase, lowercase

I'm checking 2 program config file paths from the registry. Sometimes one gets stored with a lowercase c, the other with an uppercase C which then doesn't work with a simple string comparison.

What I want to accomplish is basically that

```
"C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json" == "c:\MyPath\MyConfig.json"
```

But

```
"C:\MyPath\myconfig.json" != "C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json"
```

//Edit: I just noticed windows is not case sensitive at all, so latter codeblock is not even required. Sorry, i should have checked that in first place, but i always thought windows is case sensitive in paths, but it's indeed not it seems.

Is there something like `Path.Compare(p1, p2)` or is the only way to do that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.Equals()` to compare two pathes (strings).

The following returns `true`:

```
var equal = String.Equals(@"C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json", @"c:\MyPath\MyConfig.json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); //or StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
```

**UPDATE (after question update)**

You should compare root and rest part of string:

```
var path1 = @"C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json";
var path2 = @"c:\MyPath\myConfig.json";
    
var rootEqual = String.Equals(Path.GetPathRoot(path1), Path.GetPathRoot(path2), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // true

var withoutRootEqual = String.Equals(path1.Substring(Path.GetPathRoot(path1).Length), path2.Substring(Path.GetPathRoot(path2).Length)); //false

var equal = rootEqual && withoutRootEqual;
```

Using this approach the results are:

```
"C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json" && "C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json" -> true
"C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json" && "c:\MyPath\MyConfig.json" -> true
"C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json" && "C:\MyPath\myConfig.json" -> false
"C:\MyPath\MyConfig.json" && "c:\MyPath\myConfig.json" -> false
```

Note: this will work on Windows only because root in Linux is different, but needed result can be achieved by the similar way.

Comment: Hey, thank you, but wouldn't this ignore any case in the string? I still would like that eg. MyConfig.json and myconfig.json would make a difference.

Comment: @Taki7o7, yes, it will ignore case in whole string. There is no any mentions that you need to check case in other string part.

Comment: yeh sorry, i should have been more clear on that, my fault

Comment: @Taki7o7, see updated answer

Comment: Sorry once more, String.Equals works in my case, as i just noticed windows is not case sensitive at all.